# Best way to run a function 10 times, at 10 second intervals

Tags: java, android, loops, class, iteration

Basically I have a function that loads questions for a trivia game.  Each game has 10 rounds. Currently I have it in a four loop and tried using CountDownTimer but it would still iterate through and call the function 10 times right away. Just looking on some advice on how to call a round that lasts 10 seconds and then move to the next round.

```java
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int questionCount = 0;
    int textUpdate = 0;

    Boolean readFlag = true;
    Button answerOneBtn, answerTwoBtn, answerThreeBtn, answerFourBtn;
    TextView questionTextView;

    int playerScore = 0;
    Game currentGame = new Game(questionCount, readFlag, playerScore);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        currentGame.questionList.AnswersJumbled();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Log.e("Error", "For Loop is Running");
            playGame();
        }

        answerOneBtn = findViewById(R.id.AnswerOneButton);
        answerTwoBtn = findViewById(R.id.AnswerTwoButton);
        answerThreeBtn = findViewById(R.id.AnswerThreeButton);
        answerFourBtn = findViewById(R.id.AnswerFourButton);
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.questionText);

        answerOneBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            currentGame.playerOneSelection = answerOneBtn.getText().toString();
            Log.e("error", currentGame.playerOneSelection);
        });

        answerTwoBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            currentGame.playerOneSelection = answerTwoBtn.getText().toString();
            Log.e("error", currentGame.playerOneSelection);
        });

        answerThreeBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            currentGame.playerOneSelection = answerThreeBtn.getText().toString();
            Log.e("error", currentGame.playerOneSelection);
        });

        answerFourBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            currentGame.playerOneSelection = answerFourBtn.getText().toString();
            Log.e("error", currentGame.playerOneSelection);
        });
    }

    public void playGame() {
        answerOneBtn = findViewById(R.id.AnswerOneButton);
        answerTwoBtn = findViewById(R.id.AnswerTwoButton);
        answerThreeBtn = findViewById(R.id.AnswerThreeButton);
        answerFourBtn = findViewById(R.id.AnswerFourButton);
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.questionText);

        currentGame.loadQuestion(questionCount);
        questionTextView.setText(currentGame.currentQuestion);
        answerOneBtn.setText(currentGame.firstAnswer);
        answerTwoBtn.setText(currentGame.secondAnswer);
        answerThreeBtn.setText(currentGame.thirdAnswer);
        answerFourBtn.setText(currentGame.fourthAnswer);

        questionCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user15358848 I tried Timer and couldn't get it to work, it still went through it a few times.  Not sure what was wrong with my implementation

Comment: You should probably use a `Handler`. Also it's useful for us to see the code you've tried, even if you think it hasn't got you anywhere it shows research effort and helps us understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a bit of digging and being pointed in a general direction by the comments I found that the right answer was a handler.

My for loop now looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        handler.postDelayed(() -> playGame(), 10000 * i);
        playerAnswered = false;
        playerScore += currentGame.checkPlayerAnswer(currentGame.playerOneSelection);

    }
```